# My Provisioning Module doesn't show in the list of Module

Tags: php, web-hosting, whmcs

I Try to create a Provisioning Module on WHMCs. Base on WHMCS documents when I create this type of module I have to name that with alphanumeric in lower case and then put the module in the `Module->Server`. I did, but my module doesn't show up in module list when I try to create a new product/service.

```
WHMCS
|
|__ Modules
    |
    |__ Servers
        |
        |__mymodule
           |__hooks.php
           |__mymodule.php
           |__templates
           |__lib
```

And my another question is: I want to get extra information from a client when the client tries to buy my product such as DNS or IP and etc. 
where should I add these fields? in the hooks? or somewhere else?

sorry for bad English :))

Answer (score 0):

I found the first problem solution by adding just module at the end of the name of my module Directory.
BUt steel problem with additional custom fields when clients want to purchase a product or service like IP address, etc.

Comment: can you please help i have used sample code from doc. and module is not showing up
thank you

Comment: thanks for yout time its resolved now i was finding Provisioning module in list's of module but its named : Demo Provisioning defined in code